# Modify JS contact form to open in a new window

Tags: javascript, contact-form

I have this contact form, but I don´t know nothing about js and I need that when the user make clic on the submit button, the form send him to "thanks" page.

Thanks.

```js
                success: function() {
                    // Enable button & show success message
                    $("#btnSubmit").attr("disabled", false);
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                    $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
                error: function() {
                    // Fail message
                    $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                    $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                    //clear all fields
                    $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
                },
            })
        },
        filter: function() {
            return $(this).is(":visible");
        },
    });

    $("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab("show");
    });
});

// When clicking on Full hide fail/success boxes
$('#name').focus(function() {
    $('#success').html('');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add the following at the end of the success function (assuming that your thank you page is at thanks.html):

```
location.href="thanks.html"
```

or if ou are passing your contact form details to another page (eg:contact.php) then you can add this at the end of that page to redirect following successful addition of the client to the database, or succdessfulk email function - or whatever you are doing.

```
header("Location: thanks.html");
```

note that if you redirect from the contact.php page then you do not really need to do it via AJAX - the main benefit of using AJAX is to interact with php pages / database etc and return content to the same page - without reloading the page or leaving it. If you want to leavbe the page follonig the form submission, then really you should just use a straight form submission to the php page that can deal with the input and redirect to the thank you page.